# How to make a cylindrical collider for a cylindrical mesh in UE4

Tags: collision-detection, unreal, unreal-4

When I am importing Axis Alligend cylindrical mesh in UE4 here is what I get as an automatically generated collider:

[image]

But if I rotate the mesh in Maya and again exprot FBX to improt in UE4 here is what I get:

[image]

As you can see the object is the same but the collider is much worse. How can I make the same callider in spite of the orientation of the cylinderical mesh?

BTW if I remove collider and do auto convex collider:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

Which is very good but the problem is that I want it to be generate from the beginning and not later when I edit the mesh collider. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [RuntimeMeshComponent](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/runtime-mesh-component) which is free and created by  [Chris](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/profile/Chris)

You can procedurally generate a mesh and add its collider too.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply add a capsule collider provided by unreal instead. It is easy. Just add component on existing mesh. You can rotate your collider to match your axis.

Comment: maybe because they do not exist?